# How to debug an executable in visual studio using pdb file and source code in c++?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

I have an executable, its pdb file, and the corresponding source in VS2010/2012. How can I debug the exe which gives the same effect as debugging in conventional ways.

It would be great if you can mention steps. Thanks :)

Comment: If you don't want to create a proper project then use the Visual C++ > General > Makefile project template.    Just set the "Output" field to the EXE file, pressing F5 now starts that EXE with the debugger automatically attached.

Answer (score 4):

You can open a .exe as a project (without creating any additional project files and such):

1. Put the .pdb file next to the .exe
2. Start Visual Studio
3. File -> Open -> Project/Solution
4. Find your .exe and click Open
5. Start debugging